# Magento, Login Redirect Issue

Tags: php, magento, authentication

When logging in to the admin panel I am redirected to a url such as follows:

```
http://website.com/index.php/admin120487/index/index/key/3174c9146a5ab0ed3743085e265fa2f4/
```

The last key parameter is changed every time.

Can you guys suggest me how to fix this. The username and password is fine. But when submit it goes to this url with login page.

Comment: Are able to login in admin or not ? Try another browser. It could be cookies issue. Or try to clear the browsers cache and cookies.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is SaveHandler.php file in magento? I got the solution but not able to find this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the php version. My Php version on server is 7.0 Something.

Now update and comment your files with following code

```
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php

    public function renewSession()
     {
    /*$this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName());
    $this->regenerateSessionId();

    $sessionHosts = $this->getSessionHosts();
    $currentCookieDomain = $this->getCookie()->getDomain();
    if (is_array($sessionHosts)) {
        foreach (array_keys($sessionHosts) as $host) {
            // Delete cookies with the same name for parent domains
            if (strpos($currentCookieDomain, $host) > 0) {
                $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName(), null, $host);
            }
        }
    }*/

    return $this;
}
```